# Can I combine AnyChart Bubble charts and AnyStock charts?

Tags: anychart

I want to have a AnyStock candlestick chart and have a bubble chart over it to show some stuff but I cant figure out how to combine them

Answer (score 0):

> You don't have to do anything special to combine series in AnyChart: if series are compatible you just use them together with no fuss.

**Source:** [Combining Series | Basic Charts | AnyChart Documentation](https://docs.anychart.com/Basic_Charts/Combining_Series)

Here you want to combine [AnyStock Candlestick Series](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Series/Japanese_Candlestick) with [Bubble Chart](https://docs.anychart.com/Basic_Charts/Bubble_Chart). Unfortunately, it seems that they are not compatible: [anychart.enums.StockSeriesType](https://api.anychart.com/v8/anychart.enums.StockSeriesType)

> **anychart.enums.StockSeriesType** lists all series compatible within **Stock Charts**

No *bubble* here.

However, you can use a [Japanese Candlestick Chart](https://docs.anychart.com/Basic_Charts/Japanese_Candlestick_Chart). It is part of [Basic Cartesian](https://docs.anychart.com/Quick_Start/Modules#basic_cartesian) charts, just like the **Bubble Chart** you need.

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(() => {
  let candlestickData = [
    [Date.UTC(2007, 07, 23), 23.55, 23.88, 23.38, 23.62],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 07, 24), 22.65, 23.7, 22.65, 23.36],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 07, 25), 22.75, 23.7, 22.69, 23.44],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 07, 26), 23.2, 23.39, 22.87, 22.92],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 07, 27), 23.98, 24.49, 23.47, 23.49]
  ];
  
  let bubbleData = [  
    [Date.UTC(2007, 07, 23), 20, 1],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 07, 24), 22, 2],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 07, 25), 25, 3],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 07, 26), 21, 2],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 07, 27), 26, 1]
  ];

  let chart = anychart.candlestick();
  
  chart.candlestick(candlestickData);
  chart.bubble(bubbleData);
  chart.container("container");
  chart.draw();
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-cartesian.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```